# Where can I see when was the last time a given Slack user logged in?

Tags: slack

Where can I see when was the last time a given Slack user logged in?

Answer (score 6):

To get the last time a user logged in, take a look at the API method [`team.accessLogs`](https://api.slack.com/methods/team.accessLogs). It will give you the timestamp of the last login for every user (date_last).

Note that this API method works for paid plans only.

See also my [other answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50280153/way-to-get-timestamp-of-last-activity-for-all-slack-users/50292317#50292317).